# Loop through multi dimensional object

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Is there a more efficient way to loop through structure like following than doing for() for every level there is ?

```
[{a:foo,b:[{a:bar},{a:bar}]},{a:bar,b:[]},...]
```

I need to filter out all the items which property `a` contains certain data and if it has property `b` with some elements then loop through those also.
I was thinking of using filter method, but can't seem to figure how to use it efficiently.

Comment: Recursion is what you need

Comment: Are you suggesting of using filter only in one level and other levels handle by recursion and loop?

Comment: You have to clarify what exactly the results you want to get for the example above

Comment: I have multidimension object array and I want to filter out all objects which have property with certain string value. Search functionality.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and its collection of awesome methods.

```
var collection = [{a:foo,b:[{a:bar},{a:bar}]},{a:bar,b:[]},...];

var filteredCollection = _.chain(collection)
                             .flattenDeep()
                             .filter(function(item) { return item.a === 'foo'; });
```

This is not working code per say, you will need to do some of the work to make the loop go through each piece to flatten them individually, I just give you the tools to do the job easier.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for this. I have restricted use of third-party libraries, but that `flattenDeep()` gave me clarification, that I have to use hash table where I store all elements in one level.

Comment: functional programming is an incredible tool to deal with these types of situations, but its also a new difficult way of thinking. If you are interested in more functional programming an awesome place to see more in from Jafar Husain the tech lead from netflix - https://github.com/jhusain/learnrx

Answer (score 0):

guess, I am late, but still, I would do it like...

```
function filter(obj){
    if(obj.constructor === Array){
        var arry = [];        
        obj.forEach(function(item){
            var tmp = filter(obj);
            if(tmp) arrypush(tmp);
        });
        return arry;
    }
    if(obj.a && obj.a.contains('ignore')) // modify this to your filter condition
        return;
    if(!ob.b || !obj.b.constructor === Array)
        return obj;
    var newObj={};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
    });
    newObj.b = filter(obj.b);
    return newObj;
}
```